# Websocket: Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb, stomp

Could not find a solution to the other posted questions.

Our web socket service is running on HTTP in Kubernetes and we have enabled ELB(Elastic Load balancer). The client is connecting using stomp.js.
The client is calling ELB, ELB redirects the request to the Spring cloud gateway and the gateway is calling the web socket service. All this works fine when everything is running on HTTP.

But after enabling CloudFront on AWS and running UI and ELB on HTTPS, when we try to connect Websocket from HTTPS UI(Client) and only ELB is on HTTPS, it redirects the request to the gateway with HTTP and from there to Web socket service,
We get Handshake failure at the backend and on the browser, we are getting a response with status "Cancelled".

Any idea what could be the reason for the issue.?

Comment: Have you changed the connection scheme from `ws://` to `wss://`?

Comment: @chehsunliu Yes, moved the socket service to HTTPS.